# Problema con código para agregar accordions, no me muestra el contenido

Tags: html

Este es el código, el accordion lo hice dentro de una table con pestañas... las pestañas muestran su contenido pero el accordion no me lo muestra, cuando pulso sobre cualquiera de los 3 botones no muestra nada, alguien sabe? Muchas gracias!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/open-iconic/font/css/open-iconic-bootstrap.min.css">

    <title>HotelExpress</title>
  </head> 
  <body background="fondos/fondo6.jpg">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light fixed-top" style="background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Hoteles</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="true" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home</a> </li>
          <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="about.html">Búsqueda</a> </li>
          <li class="nav-item active"> <a class="nav-link" href="precios.html">Términos y Condiciones</a> </li>
          <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="contacto.html">Contacto</a> </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="container-fluid"><br>
      <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1 align="center">Guía de hoteles</h1>
      </div>
      <nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
        <ol class="breadcrumb">
          <li class="breadcrumb-item" style="margin: -0.7%0;"><a href="index.html" style="color: rgba(239,184,16,1);">Home</a></li>
          <li class="breadcrumb-item" style="margin: -0.7%0;"><a href="about.html" style="color: rgba(239,184,16,1);">Búsqueda</a></li>
          <li class="breadcrumb-item active" style="margin: -0.7%0;" aria-current="precios.html">Términos y Condiciones</li>
        </ol>
      </nav>
      <br>

      <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" id="compara-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#compara" role="tab" aria-controls="compara" aria-selected="true">Compara</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" id="tarjetas-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#tarjetas" role="tab" aria-controls="tarjetas" aria-selected="false">Tarjetas</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" id="comentarios-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#comentarios" role="tab" aria-controls="comentarios" aria-selected="false">Comentarios</a>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
        <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="compara" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="compara-tab"><br>

          <h1>Términos y Condiciones de los Precios:</h1><br>
          <div class="table-responsive">      
            <table class="table table-striped">
              <thead class="thead-dark">
                <th>Estrellas</th>
                <th>Asturias</th>
                <th>Bahamas</th>
                <th>Río Cádiz</th>
                <th>Ciudad del Cabo</th>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td><span class="oi oi-star"></span></td>
                  <td>$120</td>
                  <td>$140</td>
                  <td>$160</td>
                  <td>$180</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td><span class="oi oi-star"></span><span class="oi oi-star"></span></td>
                  <td>$220</td>
                  <td>$240</td>
                  <td>$260</td>
                  <td>$280</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td><span class="oi oi-star"></span><span class="oi oi-star"></span><span class="oi oi-star"></span></td>
                  <td>$320</td>
                  <td>$340</td>
                  <td>$360</td>
                  <td>$380</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td><span class="oi oi-star"></span><span class="oi oi-star"></span><span class="oi oi-star"></span><span class="oi oi-star"></span></td>
                  <td>$420</td>
                  <td>$440</td>
                  <td>$460</td>
                  <td>$480</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td><span class="oi oi-star"></span><span class="oi oi-star"></span><span class="oi oi-star"></span><span class="oi oi-star"></span><span class="oi oi-star"></span></td>
                  <td>$520</td>
                  <td>$540</td>
                  <td>$560</td>
                  <td>$580</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>    
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="tarjetas" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tarjetas-tab">
          <div class="accordion" id="accordionTarjetas">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
                <h5 class="mb-0">
                  <button class="btn btn-link" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseBasica" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseBasica">
                    Tarjeta Basica
                  </button>
                </h5>
              </div>

              <div id="collapseBasica" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordionTarjetas">
                <div class="card-body">
                  Podes reservar en hasta 6 cuotas sin interés.
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-header" id="headingTwo">
                <h5 class="mb-0">
                  <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseVIP" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseVIP">
                    Tarjeta VIP
                  </button>
                </h5>
              </div>
              <div id="collapseVIP" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordionTarjetas">
                <div class="card-body">
                  Podes reservar en hasta 8 cuotas sin interés.
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-header" id="headingThree">
                <h5 class="mb-0">
                  <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseBlack" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseBlack">
                    Tarjeta Black
                  </button>
                </h5>
              </div>
              <div id="collapseBlack" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-parent="#accordionTarjetas">
                <div class="card-body">
                  Podes reservar en hasta 12 cuotas sin interés.
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </body>
   </html>
```

Intenté de muchas maneras o agregando otros botones pero no me funciona igualmente, no se si hay un error de sintaxis o es otro el problema...
Sepan que soy muy nuevo en esto psique si hay un error grave disculpen 
Ahi agregue todo el código, ese es completo y le agregué el "show" pero aun así no me muestra el contenido...

Comment: El problema lo tienes en "tab-pane fade" tienes que poner "tab-pane fade show" o quitarle directamente la clase "fade", de esta manera se verá el acordeón.

Comment: Agregaste las librerías js que se requieren? jquery, popper y  bootstrap.js ?

Comment: ahi agregue el código completo para que vean... le agregué "show" y nada, sigue sin mostrarme el contenido

Comment: estas son las librerías que tengo: <script src="node_modules/jQuery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/Popper.js/dist/Popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

Comment: ¿Al final lo solucionaste?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

el error está en que no estas añadiendo los scripts que necesita bootstrap de forma correcta. Espero ayudar.

En tu head añadí jquery:

```
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/open-iconic/font/css/open-iconic-bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- SCRIPT JQUERY -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <title>HotelExpress</title>
</head>
```

Y al final del body añadí Popper.js y bootstrap.js, ejemplo:

```
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
    </div>
    <!-- SCRIPTS -->
    <!-- POPPER -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- BOOTSTRAP.JS -->
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

Ejemplo completo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/open-iconic/font/css/open-iconic-bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- SCRIPT JQUERY -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <title>HotelExpress</title>
</head>

<body background="fondos/fondo6.jpg">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light fixed-top" style="background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Hoteles</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="true" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home</a> </li>
                <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="about.html">Búsqueda</a> </li>
                <li class="nav-item active"> <a class="nav-link" href="precios.html">Términos y Condiciones</a> </li>
                <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="contacto.html">Contacto</a> </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="container-fluid"><br>
        <div class="jumbotron">
            <h1 align="center">Guía de hoteles</h1>
        </div>
        <nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
            <ol class="breadcrumb">
                <li class="breadcrumb-item" style="margin: -0.7%0;"><a href="index.html" style="color: rgba(239,184,16,1);">Home</a></li>
                <li class="breadcrumb-item" style="margin: -0.7%0;"><a href="about.html" style="color: rgba(239,184,16,1);">Búsqueda</a></li>
                <li class="breadcrumb-item active" style="margin: -0.7%0;" aria-current="precios.html">Términos y Condiciones</li>
            </ol>
        </nav>
        <br>

        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active" id="compara-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#compara" role="tab" aria-controls="compara" aria-selected="true">Compara</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" id="tarjetas-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#tarjetas" role="tab" aria-controls="tarjetas" aria-selected="false">Tarjetas</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" id="comentarios-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#comentarios" role="tab" aria-controls="comentarios" aria-selected="false">Comentarios</a>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
            <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="compara" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="compara-tab"><br>

                <h1>Términos y Condiciones de los Precios:</h1><br>
                <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table class="table table-striped">
                        <thead class="thead-dark">
                            <th>Estrellas</th>
                            <th>Asturias</th>
                            <th>Bahamas</th>
                            <th>Río Cádiz</th>
                            <th>Ciudad del Cabo</th>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td><span class="oi oi-star"></span></td>
                                <td>$120</td>
                                <td>$140</td>
                                <td>$160</td>
                                <td>$180</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><span class="oi oi-star"></span><span class="oi oi-star"></span></td>
                                <td>$220</td>
                                <td>$240</td>
                                <td>$260</td>
                                <td>$280</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><span class="oi oi-star"></span><span class="oi oi-star"></span><span class="oi oi-star"></span></td>
                                <td>$320</td>
                                <td>$340</td>
                                <td>$360</td>
                                <td>$380</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><span class="oi oi-star"></span><span class="oi oi-star"></span><span class="oi oi-star"></span><span class="oi oi-star"></span></td>
                                <td>$420</td>
                                <td>$440</td>
                                <td>$460</td>
                                <td>$480</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><span class="oi oi-star"></span><span class="oi oi-star"></span><span class="oi oi-star"></span><span class="oi oi-star"></span><span class="oi oi-star"></span></td>
                                <td>$520</td>
                                <td>$540</td>
                                <td>$560</td>
                                <td>$580</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="tarjetas" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tarjetas-tab">
                <div class="accordion" id="accordionTarjetas">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
                            <h5 class="mb-0">
                                <button class="btn btn-link" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseBasica" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseBasica">
                                    Tarjeta Basica
                                </button>
                            </h5>
                        </div>

                        <div id="collapseBasica" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordionTarjetas">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                Podes reservar en hasta 6 cuotas sin interés.
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-header" id="headingTwo">
                            <h5 class="mb-0">
                                <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseVIP" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseVIP">
                                    Tarjeta VIP
                                </button>
                            </h5>
                        </div>
                        <div id="collapseVIP" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordionTarjetas">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                Podes reservar en hasta 8 cuotas sin interés.
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-header" id="headingThree">
                            <h5 class="mb-0">
                                <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseBlack" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseBlack">
                                    Tarjeta Black
                                </button>
                            </h5>
                        </div>
                        <div id="collapseBlack" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-parent="#accordionTarjetas">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                Podes reservar en hasta 12 cuotas sin interés.
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- SCRIPTS -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Sos un genio Chabon! me salvaste! no sabia por que no me funcionaba y lo repasé una y otra vez... gracias!